# Custom php Login Form: using a modal

Tags: php, email, authentication, passwords

I am trying to get my login php working. I can't find what's wrong. I've had it working before, but it stopped all of the sudden. I am using bootstrap also, but I don't think that would cause any problems. Everything between the php and the form seems to match up. I am using a javascript and css modal for the login form, but I don't think that would effect it either.

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {

echo "Successfully Logged In!"; 

//header("Location: index.php");

}

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);

$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" . $email . "' and password = '" . md5($password) . "'");
?>
<!--<script>
    alert("<?php echo 'Result is: '.$result; ?>");
</script> -->
<?php
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row;

if ($row != NULL) {

    $_SESSION['usr_id'] = $row['id'];

    $_SESSION['usr_name'] = $row['name'];

    // header("Location: index.php");

} else {

    $errormsg = "Incorrect Email or Password!!!";

}

}

?>
```

Here is my login modal with the form:

```
<!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="login" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
    <div class='js-fade fade-in is-paused'>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</span>
                <form role="form" action="index.php" method="post" name="loginform">

                                        <fieldset>

                                            <legend>Login</legend>



                                            <div class="form-group">

                                                <label for="name">Email</label>

                                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required class="form-control" />

                                            </div>



                                            <div class="form-group">

                                                <label for="name">Password</label>

                                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Your Password" required class="form-control" />

                                            </div>


                                            <div class="form-group">

                                                <input type="submit" name="login" value="login" class="btn btn-info login" role="button" />

                                            </div>

                                        </fieldset>
                                            <div class="signupbtn">
                                                <li><a href="signup/index.php" class="noaccount btn btn-info" id="signupbtn">Don't have an account? Sign Up here.</a></li>
                                            </div>
                                    </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Navbar:

```
<!-- Nav Bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-left">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand brand" href="#" style="font-family: Warnes">Unleasht</a>
        </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="navbarli"><a href="#" class="navbarli">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="navbarli"><a href="#about" class="navbarli">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li class="navbarli"><a href="#music" class="navbarli" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">MUSIC</a></li>
            <li class="navbarli"><a href="#contact" class="navbarli" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

            <?php
            function loggedIn(){
            if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id']))
            { echo '<li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">'. $_SESSION['user'] .'<span class="caret"></span></a>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">'. $_SESSION['usr_name'] .'</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a action="login/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>';
            }else{
                unset($_SESSION['usr_id']);
                echo '<li><a href="#login" class="navbarli" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login" id="loginbtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in navbarli"></span> Login</a></li>';
                }
            }
            loggedIn();
            ?>

        </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And yes, I know that md5 is not a good thing to use for passwords because of security. For now, I am just trying to get the login working, then I will make the switch from md5 to something else.

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."* or *"Security isn't important now..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?

Comment: Have you checked for errors in your browser's console and in your error logs?

Answer (score 0):

You can not set $_SESSION['usr_id'] after you have sent any header, try following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {
    echo "Successfully Logged In!"; 
}elseif (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" . $email . "' and password = '" . md5($password) . "'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['usr_id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['usr_name'] = $row['name'];
        echo "OK fine";
    } else {
        echo "Incorrect Email or Password!!!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try" this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: In addition, you can set SESSION variables anytime - you just cannot *start* a session after headers have been sent. Keep in mind the OP said, *" I've had it working before, but it stopped all of the sudden."*